# I get the error message "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when trying to run code

Tags: r, reactable

Creating a reactable in R, I was successfully able to use the colorRamp function to make a color scale for the "Rank" column. However, when I copy the code to the PVI VALUE column, I get the error message "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Why can I not simply paste the "style" part of the code in the PVI VALUE column to achieve the identical color scale? I think it is because the "value" of the PVI_Value column is string - so how do I make the function use the "Rank" values instead?

```
RtoDColorPalette <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("red","blue"))(x),maxColorValue = 255)

MasterIndexTable <- reactable(
  HousePVI,
  columns = list(
    ID_No = colDef(show = FALSE),
    State = colDef(defaultSortOrder = "asc", width = 60),
    District_Number = colDef(name = "District", defaultSortOrder = "asc", width = 75),
    First_Name = colDef(name = "First Name", width = 120),
    Last_Name = colDef(name = "Last Name", width = 120),
    Member_Party = colDef(name = "Party", width = 60),
    PVI_Lean = colDef(name = "PVI Lean", width = 60, show = FALSE),
    PVI_Value_Absolute = colDef(name = "PVI Value Absolute", width = 60, show = FALSE),
    PVI_Value = colDef(name = "PVI Value",
                   style = function(value) {
                     normalized <- (value - min(HousePVI$Rank))/(max(HousePVI$Rank) -     min(HousePVI$Rank))
                     color <- RtoDColorPalette(normalized)
                     list(background = color, color = 'white')
                   }
              ),
    Rank = colDef(name = "Rank - Most Republican (1) to Most Democratic (435)",  
              style = function(value) {
                normalized <- (value - min(HousePVI$Rank))/(max(HousePVI$Rank) - min(HousePVI$Rank))
                color <- RtoDColorPalette(normalized)
                list(background = color, color = 'white')
                }
              )
    ),
  sortable = TRUE,
  filterable = TRUE,
  searchable = TRUE,
  showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
  pageSizeOptions = c(10,20,435),
  striped = TRUE,
  compact = TRUE,
  theme = fivethirtyeight () 
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right. The `value` passed to the style function is the `value` of the column on which you want to apply the style.

However, one option to style a column based on the value of another column would be to make use of the optional `index` argument (there is also an optional `name` argument, see [Cell Styling](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/conditional-styling.html#cell-styling)) which provides the row index, i.e. using the index we could color based on `HousePVI$Rank[index]`.

Using a fake example:

```
library(reactable)

set.seed(123)

RtoDColorPalette <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("red", "blue"))(x), maxColorValue = 255)

HousePVI <- data.frame(
  ID_No = 1:10,
  State = LETTERS[1:10],
  Rank = sample(1:10)
)

reactable(
  HousePVI,
  columns = list(
    ID_No = colDef(show = FALSE),
    Rank = colDef(
      name = "Rank (Most Republican (1) to Most Democratic (435)", width = 230,
      style = function(value) {
        normalized <- (value - min(HousePVI$Rank)) / (max(HousePVI$Rank) - min(HousePVI$Rank))
        color <- RtoDColorPalette(normalized)
        list(background = color, color = "white")
      }
    ),
    State = colDef(
      style = function(value, index) {
        normalized <- (HousePVI$Rank[index] - min(HousePVI$Rank)) / (max(HousePVI$Rank) - min(HousePVI$Rank))
        color <- RtoDColorPalette(normalized)
        list(background = color, color = "white")
      }
    )
  ),
  theme = reactableTheme(
    color = "black",
    backgroundColor = "white",
    borderColor = "black",
    stripedColor = "aliceblue"
  )
)
```

[image]